# Remove a string from text file

Tags: java, file, io

Here is my code to remove a string from file.
This code deletes the string from the temporary file generated
 --but do not replace the original file with the temporary file which is edited.

original file remains as it is. editing takes place in the temp file and it do not renames to original file

```
 try{
    File inFile = new File("ext.txt");

  if (!inFile.isFile()) {
    System.out.println("Parameter is not an existing file");
    return;
  }

  File tempFile = new File(inFile.getAbsolutePath()+".txt");

  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile));
  PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

  String line = null;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

    if (!line.trim().equals(mystring)) {

      pw.println(line);
      pw.flush();
    }

  }

  pw.close();
  br.close();
   inFile.delete();
   tempFile.renameTo(inFile);

     if (!inFile.delete()) {
    System.out.println("Could not delete file");
    return;
  }

    if (!tempFile.renameTo(inFile))
    System.out.println("Could not rename file");

}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: plz read the last line. the code is not replacing the the original file with the edited one.

Comment: original file remains as it is. editing takes place in the temp file and it do not renames to original file

Comment: would u plz share the code if u have one .

Comment: Thanks . i have solved the problem . by setting writable mode true.

Comment: inFile.getAbsolutePath()  ----- this will return the full qualified name of the file and on top of that you are concatenating one more '.txt' , so basically your tempfile is 'ext.txt.txt'.  just a thought

Comment: correct but the problem was with deleting the file and renaming it.
it is solved now thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running perfectly fine. You need to store the boolean values file.delete and file.rename, and use those values in your "if" conditions. The flaw is, you are trying to delete and rename the same file which has already been renamed and deleted, so its failing your if condition. Try doing something like this:

```
       boolean isDeleted = inFile.delete();
       boolean isRenamed = tempFile.renameTo(inFile);

         if (!isDeleted) {
        System.out.println("Could not delete file");
        return;
      }

        if (!isRenamed)
        System.out.println("Could not rename file");
```